# Odd VBA Boolean Behavior

Tags: excel, vba

I am having odd boolean comparison behavior. I set a boolean variable the following way:

```
bMacroRun = swApp.RunMacro2(pubMacroPath, "GetMassComps", "SwGetMassMain", swRunMacroDefault, swMacroError)
```

This sends a command to Solidworks to run a macro in that environment. The boolean is for whether the macro successfully ran. However, when I use it in a conditional, it does not evaluate correctly. With the code paused right after that line, I typed the following into the immediate window:

```
Debug.Print True=True
True
Debug.Print False=True
False
Debug.Print bMacroRun
True
Debug.Print bMacroRun=True
False
Debug.Print Not bMacroRun
True
```

I have set `Option Explicit` and the variable is declared within the procedure and nowhere else. It also appears as True in the Local Window:

[image]

Also it appears to happen randomly. It was working correctly for a while and then stopped.

Thoughts?

-EDIT-

I just discovered that if I declare another variable bDummy and don't give it a type:

```
Dim bDummy
Dim bMacroRun       As Boolean
```

And then do the following:

```
bMacroRun = swApp.RunMacro2(pubMacroPath, "GetMassComps", "SwGetMassMain", swRunMacroDefault, swMacroError)
bDummy = bMacroRun
```

Then it evaluates correctly:

```
Debug.Print bDummy
True
Debug.Print bDummy=True
True
```

Per Jerry's comment, I also ran the following:

```
Debug.Print CInt(bMacroRun)
 1 
Debug.Print CInt(bDummy)
-1
```

So it appears that Solidworks is returning 1 for True which according to Jerry's comment is false in Excel VBA. This is odd because Solidworks API uses VBA as well.

Comment: Why would you ever do `If True = True Then`?  you simply need `If bMacroRun Then`

Comment: That's what I originally had, and I changed it to this which fixed it for a while and now it's back again

Comment: Ok, so in C and many other languages any value except 0 is true.  In VBA only -1 is `True`.  So when you compare something that is true (any positive number for example) with `True` the result will be false because your positive number is not equal to -1.    You need to compare  your thing to `False` because everyone agrees that 0 is `False` because Your macro is returning something that is not 0 or -1.